# Don't want to Sum or Count measure

Tags: ssas, cube, msbi

Here is the situation, I have number with total numbers and i put all in Cube. Just want to see what is showing up in DB rather than sum or count.

I tried Aggregated function none but it's not bring up anything.

Pleas suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation function **none** shows numbers only if all of the following conditions are met:

- You are slicing by dimension ID hierarchy. For example, for Dim Customer - slicing by CustomerID.
- All dimensions which are regular dimensions of your measure group have to be present in your query.
- You should not use [All] member of the dimensions.

As you see, **none** aggregation is quite restrictive.
For your task - see what is in DB or on leaf level - try DRILLTHROUGH function.